# Retain query string param after submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On my website I use MVC Authentication, if a user wants to reset his password, he clicks on 'Forgot Password' then he gets by email a link with a unique code to reset his password.

My issue is if for some reason the reset fails (for example- password and password confirmation don't match etc) then it returns to the View without the unique code that was generated in the link that the user got by email and the reset password won't work afterwards (`code` query string param)

How can I keep the query string unique code when the reset fails and return it to the View?

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
{
      if (!ModelState.IsValid)
      {
           return View(model);
      }
      var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
      if (user != null)
      {
           var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, model.Code, model.Password);
           if (result.Succeeded)
           {
                return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
           }
      }
       ViewBag.Error = "Password reset failed";
       return View();
}
```

And this is the form:

```
  <form id="reset-form" method="post" action="Account/ResetPassword">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Reset Password</h2>
            @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Error))
            {
                <div class="invalid">
                    @ViewBag.Error
            </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="inputField">
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="USERNAME" />
        </div>
        <div class="inputField">
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="PASSWORD" />
        </div>
        <div class="inputField">
            <input type="password" id="confirm-password" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="CONFIRM PASSWORD" />
            <input type="submit"/>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I need it to return to the View like this:

> ~/account/resetpassword?code=xyz

Comment: What is the query string parameter named and what is the code used to post to this action method?

Comment: @NightOwl888 Please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL will remain the same as what you post when the view is returned unless you do a redirect (not recommended).

However, the issue isn't that you need the URL to change after the action method runs. You need to change the URL that is *posted* to the action method to include the query string so it is there when the action method returns the view. This can be done by simply changing the URL of the form.

> Note that you should *never* hard code the URL in MVC views. Instead, you should always use `controller`, `action`, and other route values to resolve the URL using the `UrlHelper` (and related extension methods such as `ActionLink`). The routing infrastructure should be the only place where URLs exist so they can be changed in one place.

In this case the solution is to use `Html.BeginForm` to build up the form tag based on routing.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ResetPassword", "Account", new { code = "xyz" }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Reset Password</h2>
        @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Error))
        {
            <div class="invalid">
                @ViewBag.Error
        </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="inputField">
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="USERNAME" />
    </div>
    <div class="inputField">
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="PASSWORD" />
    </div>
    <div class="inputField">
        <input type="password" id="confirm-password" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="CONFIRM PASSWORD" />
        <input type="submit"/>
    </div>
}
```

Of course, you shouldn't hard code `"xyz"` here either, it should be passed to the view from the `HttpGet` `ResetPassword` method either in a Model or in `ViewBag`.

Note that if the `url` parameter of the route definition (typically in `RouteConfig.cs`) *does not contain* a parameter for `code`, it will automatically be added to the URL as a query string parameter.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much for the answer and the great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Thymeleaf and had a similar issue. Here's how I solved it using the thymeleaf functionality:

HTML:

```
<form class="forms-sample" action="/login" 
!!! th:action="@{/reset_password(token=${token})}" !!!
th:object="${passwordDto}" method="post">
             **INSERT CODE HERE**
               </form>
```

MVC Controller:

```
if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("token", tokenStr); !!!!!!!!
            return "create_password";
        }


        try {
            PasswordResetToken token = passwordResetTokenService.getByToken(tokenStr);
            User user = token.getUser();
            user = userMapper.setNewPassword(user, passwordDto);
            userService.update(user);
            passwordResetTokenService.delete(token);
            return "home";
        }catch (PasswordNotMatchException e) {
            bindingResult.rejectValue("confirmNewPassword", "password_error",
                    "Confirm password did not match.");
            model.addAttribute("token", tokenStr); !!!!!!!!
            return "create_password";
        }
        catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
            return "create_password";
        }
```

What I do is I put the token in the Model and if the post method encounters an error I make sure to add it again, before returning the view for creating a password.

The important thing to note is, as NightOwl mentioned, that the url stays the same, only the Model changes. Thats why we need to readd the token as a model attribute.